# Store my login credentials in redux-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to store my login credentials in redux-react. I'm attaching few lines of code (a part of the problem).

sksignup.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { namesactions } from '../store/display';

function Sksignup() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const showdetails = () => {
    dispatch(namesactions.updatename({ shopname, }))
  }

  const insertdata = () => { #backend code that works fine
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/register', { shopname: shopname, })
      .then( 
        navigate('/userentry')
      ) 

  <label>enter your shop name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="shopname" onChange={showdetail} />
  <button onClick={insertdata}>register</button>
```

The code related to store (created to store the docs related tp redux) folder

display.js\store:

```js
import { configureStore, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const names = createSlice({
  name: 'skdetail',
  initialState: { shopname: " ", },
  reducers: {
    updatename(state, action) {
      state.shopname = action.payload.shopname;
    }
  }
})

export const namesactions = names.actions;
export default names;
```

index.js\store:

```
import { configureStore, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import names from "./display";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    name: names.reducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

index.js\src:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './store';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store ={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I aim to retrieve the `shopname` and render it in another component like:

```
welcome, {shopname}
```

Should I need to use firebase or something to make this happen?

I have tried implementing the solutions that I learned from some tutorials, but the components are not rendering (not getting displayed)

Comment: What exactly is the problem or issue you face? You mention errors? Please [edit] to include all relevant details, including errors you have along with any code stacktraces.

Comment: Saying "it's not rendering" isn't all that helpful. How are you selecting this `state.name.shopname` state to be rendered and how are you trying to render it?

Comment: I'm just trying to store it

Comment: Store what, `shopname`? Have you provided a complete [mcve]? It doesn't appear that `shopname` is defined anywhere in `Sksignup` so you likely aren't passing what you think to your store.

Comment: @DrewReese can u just provide a snippet how to define it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253410/discussion-between-dharshini-s-and-drew-reese).

Comment: Do you mean something like `const shopname = "shopname";` locally in the component, or are you referring to `state.names.shopname` in the redux state?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the value entered in the `input` element dispatched to the store? Or do you just need a defined `shopname` value from the "form" to be passed to `insertdata` for the POST request? Or are you trying to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the shopname from the redux store and display it in another component, you can use the useSelector hook in that component to get the value from the store. Here's an example:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function Welcome() {
  const shopname = useSelector(state => state.skdetail.shopname);
  return (
    <div>
      Welcome, {shopname}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Welcome;
```